# Installing a django project, database issue

Tags: python, django

I am installing the sunlight fondation's brisket and I am really new to python, and even more to django. So I downloaded on github the project : https://github.com/sunlightlabs/brisket.

So, when I run the ./manage.py run server command, I get an error message. But I know nothing from python and django.

So now here's the error message, am I supposed to install a package ?
Could some one help ?

```
    Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.core.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x976b84c>>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 219, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 36, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 146, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 61, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 76, in load_app
    app_module = import_module(app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named brisket.influence
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have mysql for python installed. There are various ways to do this but the most common are:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

or

```
easy_install MySQL-python
```

Comment: I tried to run those commands and I got this message : Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement MySQL-python
No distributions at all found for MySQL-python

Comment: The commands work for me. But "Cannot fetch index base URL pypi.python.org/simple" is quite disturbing as this is the main package index. Without it you will not be able to install any package.

Comment: Depending on which Linux Distribution you are using you may install mysql-python through its package manager.

Comment: In fact, I mamaged to install mysqldb, using traditional apt-get method (pip failing because I am on Ubuntu). By the way, I still have a error message running the server, I updated it in my question

Comment: Maybe it helps : in the Installed_apps of my settings.py file, I suppressed : three of them brisket.util, brisket.influence and feedinator. So the "runserver" command worked in this condition, tables were created. But in my browser, I have a page of warning, telling me that brisker.util is necessary

Comment: Suppressing some of the apps in settings.py will make the software unusable, you should turn them on and try to solve the original problem.

Comment: Yes I have checked, sunlight labs produces on github feedinator... You should install it